# MILP variable takes only positive values

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to formulate a battery dispatch strategy whereby the battery only charges when there is excess energy left after self consumption.

PV_SIZE, PV_Generation are decision variables, and Power_Demand is an input. Y_SURPLUS is a binary variable, and BESSCHARGE is somewhat of a "helper" function.

I have come up with the current code so far in CVXPY, but the problem remains infeasible.

```
Y_SURPLUS[i] >= ((PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i]) - Power_Demand[i])/M,
Y_SURPLUS[i] >= 0,
Y_SURPLUS[i] <= 1,

BESSCHARGE[i] <= Y_SURPLUS[i]*M,
BESSCHARGE[i] >= 0,
BESSCHARGE[i] <= (PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i] - Power_Demand[i]) ,
BESSCHARGE[i] >= (PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i] - Power_Demand[i]) -((1-Y_SURPLUS[i])*M),

BESS_CHARGE[i] >= 0 ,
BESS_CHARGE[i] <= BESSCHARGE[i],
```

I am trying to get BESS_CHARGE[i] to be equal to (PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i]), if (PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i]) >0. Otherwise if (PV_SIZE*PV_Generation[i]) <0, BESS_CHARGE[i] should be 0.